# set up website in iis 7.5 on Lan for access in intranet

Tags: asp.net, iis

i want to setup my website in iis 7.5 to access in intranet,it's working with page with extension "home.aspx" but
 when i am using rewrite URL like "/home" it is rising error

i had done rewriting code in global.asax and it is working on my live website and on localhost also but creating problem in  intranet only

[image]

thank's in advance

Comment: Some code will help, and the global.asax part, even tho I believe that your issue is that the files with out extension are not pass from asp.net engine.

Comment: but is is working on localhot and my godaddy server

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to add "home.aspx" to "Default Documents" inside the iis

if not open "Default Documents" and add home.aspx then move it to top

these some screenshot from google just to illustrate

http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/admin/media_store/2/AA-00495/default-document.png

http://mscerts.net/image/201009/Managing%20Websites%20with%20IIS%20Manager_9.jpg